# Vagrant, can't download box

Tags: vagrant

not sure why I'm having this issue but I can't add vagrant boxes.

Using windows 10, tried on powershell and simple command prompt. same issue. It's a relatively fresh install of windows. Maybe I'm missing some required package?

first i tried this command:

```
vagrant box add hashicorp/precise32
```

and got the error:

```
The box 'hashicorp/precise32' could not be found or
could not be accessed in the remote catalog. If this is a private
box on HashiCorp's Atlas, please verify you're logged in via
`vagrant login`. Also, please double-check the name. The expanded
URL and error message are shown below:

URL: ["https://atlas.hashicorp.com/hashicorp/precise32"]
Error:
```

So I downloaded the box manually and tried this:

```
vagrant box add base64 file:///D:/downloads/vagrant_boxes/precise64.box
```

And got this error again:

```
==> box: Box file was not detected as metadata. Adding it directly...
==> box: Adding box 'base64' (v0) for provider:
    box: Unpacking necessary files from: file:///D:/downloads/vagrant_boxes/precise64.box
    box:
An error occurred while downloading the remote file. The error
message, if any, is reproduced below. Please fix this error and try
again.
```

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer here: https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/6754#issuecomment-169984218

Need to install Microsoft Visual C++ 2010

Above git forum has the link to the needed download